# Error in making table with multiple columns

Tags: tables, errors, pdf, texworks

I try to make a table with more than two columns as follows

```
\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{cc}
    Sub & $A_i$ & $B_i$ & $C_i$ & $D_i$ & $E_i$ & $F_i$ & $G_i$ & $H_i$ \\ \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular} \end{center}
```

But it shows

```
[4]
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 
                             
l.228         Sub & $A_i$ &
                            $B_i$ & $C_i$ & $D_i$ & $E_i$ & $F_i$ & $G_i$ & ...

?
```

**I want to know how to solve the error. It seems nothing wrong to me. And when I reduce the number of columns to 2, it works fine. It shows me an error when there are more than 2 columns.**

Comment: Load `array` and use in the table preamble `*{9}{c}`, not `cc`.

Comment: `{cc}` means two centred columns.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: problem solved! thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you employ a `matrix` environment (provided by the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package) in an unnumbered displayed equation instead of a `tabular` environment embedded in a `center` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' env.
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix} 
% Note: No need for '$' symbols to initiate and terminate inline math mode...
    \mathrm{Sub} & A_i & B_i & C_i & D_i & E_i & F_i & G_i & H_i \\ 
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ 
    \hline
\end{matrix} 
\]
\end{document}
```